# Unable to round-trip a simple object through MsgPack

Tags: c#, msgpack

So I'm attempting to use the MsgPack package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/MsgPack.Cli/) to round-trip a simple object to my file. I can *write* the packed message just fine, and inspecting the generated object with a binary editor shows that the data was written as I expected. However, the *unpacked* message always comes back as null. Is anyone familiar with this library and can explain what's going wrong?

```
    public class Options
    {
        public string RecordLog { get; set; }
        public string ConfigFile { get; set; }
    }

    static void TestRoundTrip()
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream("test.file", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read, 65535, true))
        {
            var packer = Packer.Create(fs, false);
            var options = new Options()
            {
                RecordLog = "log string",
                ConfigFile = "config string"
            };
            packer.Pack(options);
            packer.Dispose();
        }

        using (var fs = File.Open("test.file", FileMode.Open))
        {
            var unpacker = Unpacker.Create(fs, true);

            var opts = unpacker.Unpack<Options>();
            Console.WriteLine(opts.RecordLog);
            Console.WriteLine(opts.ConfigFile);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by doing the following in the block for unpacking:

```
    using (var fs = File.Open("test.file", FileMode.Open))
    {
        var unpacker = Unpacker.Create(fs, true);

        unpacker.Read();
        var opts = unpacker.Unpack<Options>();
        Console.WriteLine(opts.RecordLog);
        Console.WriteLine(opts.ConfigFile);
    }
```

It turns out that `unpacker.Unpack<T>()` only unpacks a message which has already been read in a call to `Read()`. I was only able to figure this out by reading the source, which is fortunately available online.